# How to pass value of pointer from map into function argument

Tags: go

So my use case is this:

#### 1. generate map of pointers to structs (cars)

#### 2. mutate map

#### 3. iterate map and pass to function

```
type Car struct {
    Model string
    Size  int
}

func getSize(car Car) {
    fmt.Println(car.Size)
}

func main() {
    cars := make(map[string]*Car)
    // fill cars with stuff
    cars["Toyota"] = &Car{
        Model: "Toyota",
        Size:  2,
    }

    for _, car := range cars {
        cars["Toyota"].Size = 4
    }

    for _, car := range cars {
        //somehow get the value of car and insert into function
        getSize(car)
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to pass the value of a pointer from a map to a function since maps don't allow you to address the pointer.

Is there any way to better go about this?

Comment: Could you please post a minimal executable go playground example? WHy are you ranging over cars to set the same key? https://play.golang.org/p/xKIlHWqJ4a9

Comment: @dm03514 not ranging over cars to set same key, im just demonstrating by setting one value

Answer (score 0):

You can dereference the cars map value during your call, which will invoke the function with the value pointed to by the car pointer:

`getSize(*car)`

---

If you don't you should receive a compilation error:

> prog.go:31:16: cannot use car (type *Car) as type Car in argument to
>   getSize

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


type Car struct {
    Model string
    Size  int
}

func getSize(car Car) {
    fmt.Println(car.Size)
}

func main() {
    cars := make(map[string]*Car)
    // fill cars with stuff
    cars["Toyota"] = &Car{
        Model: "Toyota",
        Size:  2,
    }


    cars["Toyota"].Size = 4


    for _, car := range cars {
        //somehow get the value of car and insert into function
        getSize(car)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate by what you mean by deference the cars map value? Maybe with a code example?